# Сцены Unity, оптимизация, уровни

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда делаешь уровни в игре, что разумнее - каждый уровень делать на своей сцене и подгружаться с помощью LoadScene или исхитряться с уничтожением всех объектов на экране и генерации уровня на этой же сцене? Что занимает больше места? Не висят ли после LoadScene старые сцены в памяти?

Comment: Думаю точный ответ знает только профайлер,  вроде бы после смены сцены объекты удаляются, но все сразу, что быстрее чем вручную по 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В памяти точно висят ссылки на сцены. Иначе бы нельзя было между ними переключиться.

На счет памяти: по дефолту, когда загружается сцена - всё на предыдущей сцене уничтожается. Иначе бы память утекала как река.

Однако некоторые ресурсы могут остаться загруженными. Для очистки неиспользующихся ресурсов можно воспользоваться [Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets.html). И что-то в [документации](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/iphone-BuildProcess.html)

Для просмотра, что происходит у вас с памятью, можете использовать профайлер. Например есть такой инструмент как `xCode`. Правда он для ios и кажется Android. Попробуйте посмотреть почитать информацию о нем, как работать с ним в `Unity`, думаю окажется очень полезным.
На всякий случай небольшое [видео о работе xCode с Unity](https://youtu.be/mcIdkIKfhvg).

> что разумнее - каждый уровень делать на своей сцене и подгружаться с
>   помощью LoadScene или исхитряться с уничтожением всех объектов на
>   экране и генерации уровня на этой же сцене

Разумнее действовать по обстоятельствам. Ибо здравый смысл рулед! А никак не один шаблон действий для всего и всея.

**Например**, если вы пишите простой незамысловатый `Arcanoid`, то тут можно всю логику определить в скрипте (допустим конфигурацию и расстановку блоков на каждом уровне можно запросто описать конфиге, а не использовать 100500 сцен и расстанавливать эти блоки вручную. Просто на основе конфига будет генерироваться так или иная сетка). И тогда достаточно в начале уровня по конфигу сгенерировать объекты, а по окончанию перегенерировать новую сетку с другими параметрами. Тут логично иметь один уровень и динамическую генерацию.

**Другой пример**: какая-нибудь *RPG*, для которой нужно сгенерировать карту, расположить в нужных местах врагов/предметы/порталы/секретные места/сундуки/прочее.

Согласитесь, все это описывать в конфигурации и писать много дополнительной логики для их генерации в нужных координатах с нужным углом поворота выйдет гораздо накладнее, нежели расположить все это на сценах и переключаться между ними. Представляете сколько лишней работы: надо выстроить вручную всю сцену, далее все данные о каждом необходимом объекте (коих может быть тысячи на сцене) записать в нужные конфиги, настроить логику взаимодействия между объектами сцены, далее удалить всё со сцены. И так для каждой сцены. А если нужно камешек или сундук с золотом или врага переместить в другое место - что делать? Опять всё пересоздавать, сдвигать, смотреть координаты, перезаписывать? Писать кучу кода, классов, интерфейсов взаимодействия и контроля за всем этим. Ужас ужас.

Так что делать всё на одной сцене тут выйдет себе дороже.

Итог: для анализа памяти используйте профайлер удобный, а <strike>быть или не быть, вот в чем вопрос</strike> уничтожать всё и ребилдить заново или все располагать на разных сценах - зависит от концепции, от сложности проекта и от того, на сколько хочется заморачиваться с теми или иными вещами

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: @Suvitruf не совсем понял намёк)

Comment: Не всё уничтожается. Просто как дополнение.